# How to store a very big number with hundreds of digits in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I need to store very large numbers with hundreds or thousands of digits (like 999^999) in a database. How can I do this in MySQL? What data type should I use?

Also, I will need to subtract,compare, add the numbers. Is it possible to do so in a small time with MySQL?

Comment: Why do you want to store such a big number in database?

Comment: Can you store like a string?

Comment: When you say "Is it possible to do so in a small time" do you mean to write the code that does this or are you talking about the potential performance of your application?

Comment: Do you require accuracy to the last digit?  Or, could you store your number as you listed above like 999^999?

Comment: compare will get expensive, add and subtract in mysql with little effort, not unless someone has already put a lot of effort into extending it to do big numbers. The assumptions behind your questions would appear to be , questionable.

Comment: since i need to perform operations on the numbers, i cant store them as a string;i'm talking about the potential performance;yes i require accuracy to the last digit

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a great answer but the Postgres has bindings to [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org/), the multi-precision library. If you aren't too far into your project you might consider switching databases. The MySQL docs make it clear that integer support tops out at [BIGINT], which is an 8-byte storage with about 18 places of accuracy.

the site for it is here: http://pgmp.projects.pgfoundry.org/mpz.html

I can't find any sign that anyone used the external bindings in MySQL to do something similar. To do this in MySQL you would either have to implement external bindings to a library like GMPLIB or store the data in MySQL as a [STRING] or as one of the [BLOB],[MEDIUMBLOB] types and then implement all your sorts and operations in code. That is a huge task.

Comment: This is more of a comment to the original question instead of an answer, as it doesn't provide an actual answer to the question asked. (The question asks about MySQL, and your comment refers to Postgres and GNU MP, neither of which relates to MySQL.)

Comment: Fair enough [Ken](http://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white) I've added to the comment to be more explicit about MySQL limits and his options.